# Why does function of ComPtr return a different value then &?

Tags: c++, com, directx

Why &(ComPtr.Get()) != ComPtr.GetAddressOf()?

I tryed to pass ID3D11ShaderResourcesView* to function and convert it to ** to use in CreateShaderResourceView, but it didnt work correct.

I realized, that the problem in 3 argument.

Comment: I have a quick write-up for using ComPtr [here](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr) you might find useful.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the address of the pointer that `ComPtr.Get()` returns. That's entirely different to the pointer to the object.

Comment: I thought that Get() return a pointer to the object and GetAddressOf() return a pointer to the pointer.
In the documantation it describes as "T* Get() const;" and "T** GetAddressOf();"
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cppcx/wrl/comptr-class?view=vs-2019#get

Comment: Oh, I understood. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`ComPtr.Get()` returns the held pointer **by value**, so `&(ComPtr.Get())` is taking the address of a *copy* of the held pointer.

`ComPtr.GetAddressOf()` returns the address of the held pointer itself, not a copy of it.

Had `ComPtr.Get()` returned the held pointer **by reference** instead then `&(ComPtr.Get())` would take the address of the original pointer, not a copy. But it does not return a reference.

Comment: Can I ask a bit more? I undrestood it, but I havent understood an other thing. "T CreateShaderResourceView(...)" require 3 agruments. First is the pointer to the object, which is conevrting to the parent. Second doesnt matter. Third is a pointer to the pointer of the object. Why I cant use here &(ComPtr.Get()) as 3 argument? I mean, it musn`t be important where the pointer to the object is saved, it must steel work. Function have a similar path to the object. As I think.

Comment: @Кай `CreateShaderResourceView()` returns a new object by setting the pointer passed in the 3rd argument. As I said, `ComPtr.Get()` returns a *copy* of the pointer held by the `ComPtr`. Thus `&(ComPtr.Get())` takes the address of the *copy*, not the original. Any value assigned to the copy is not assigned to the original. That is why `&(ComPtr.Get())` is not suitable for use with `CreateShaderResourceView()`, you need to use `ComPtr.GetAddtessOf()` instead, so `CreateShaderResourceView()` can update the original pointer that `ComPtr` is holding.

Comment: Ooh, such a bad mistake. It doesnt chage the object, it changes the pointer to the object =_=" Mb I need a rest) Thank you!